# Rails nested fields creation in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have three model classes related to each other.

```
 class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :marks
  belongs_to :group

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :marks,
                                reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['rate'].blank?},
                                allow_destroy: true

end
```

This class describes a student that has many marks and I want to create a Student record along with his marks.

```
 class Mark < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :student, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :subject

end
```

Marks are related both to the Subject and a Student.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :group
  has_many :marks

end
```

When I try to create the nested fields of marks in loop labeling them with subject names and passing into in it's subject_id via a loop a problem comes up - only the last nested field of marks is saved correctly, whilst other fields are ignored. Here's my form view code:

```
 <%= form_for([@group, @student]) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :student_name %>
        <%=f.label 'Student`s name'%><br>
        <%= f.text_field :student_surname %>
        <%=f.label 'Student`s surname'%><br>
        <%=f.check_box :is_payer%>
        <%=f.label 'Payer'%>
        <%= f.fields_for :marks, @student.marks  do |ff|%>
            <%@group.subjects.each do |subject| %><br>
                <%=ff.label subject.subject_full_name%><br>
                <%=ff.text_field :rate %>
                <%=ff.hidden_field :subject_id, :value => subject.id%><br>
            <%end%>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit 'Add student'%>
    <% end %>
```

Here`s my controller code:

```
class StudentsController<ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_admin!

  def new
    @student = Student.new
    @student.marks.build
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    @group.student_sort
  end

  def create
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    @student = @group.students.new(student_params)
    if @student.save
      redirect_to new_group_student_path
      flash[:notice] = 'Студента успішно додано!'
    else
      redirect_to new_group_student_path
      flash[:alert] = 'При створенні були деякі помилки!'
    end
  end


  private
  def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(:student_name, :student_surname, :is_payer, marks_attributes: [:id, :rate, :subject_id, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please share the code for saving the record?

Comment: Share your controller code.

Comment: I`ll add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@student.marks.build
```

This line will reserve an object Mark.

If you want multi marks, May be you need something like this in new action :

```
@group.subjects.each do |subject|
   @student.marks.build(:subject=> subject)
end
```

Hope useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but there`s one more. Sorry for bothering you, but how can I now assign labels for each of marks by it`s subject?

Comment: `ff.label :subject_id`, it doesn't work ? may be i didn't understand your question. sorry.